# Toshiba satellite can't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I've a Toshiba satellite laptop and I tried to get Ubuntu along with the windows. There was a black out after the Ubuntu installation was complete so I forced off my laptop but when I restarted, dual boot was working and I chose Ubuntu, but my touchpad didn't work properly, so I went to windows, deleted Ubuntu partition and started afresh.

But this time Ubuntu installation couldn't be completed as it said there was some problem with GRUB. So I went back to windows, tried to repair the boot problems with easy BCD there I learned it was in EFI mode, so I went back to boot menu, changed it to CSM and when I saved the settings and exit, my laptop wouldn't restart.The only thing I see is a black screen (power on), not even the Toshiba logo, no keys working and it wont boot from an Ubuntu pendrive either.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows was installed in EFI mode, the machine has to be in EFI mode, not CSM, to boot Windows.

Since you removed your Ubuntu partition, and by that also GRUBs boot files, it can't staqrt up.

You have two options now:

1. Find your Windows install media, boot from that and repair MBR from there.
2. Boot from Ubuntu live DVD or USB and install Ubuntu again. This will also repair GRUB.

Good luck.

Comment: This is correct *except* for one important point: On an EFI-based computer, the MBR is not involved in booting, except insofar as a "protective MBR" is part of the data structure of the GUID Partition Table (GPT). Thus, in option #1, you don't need to "repair [the] MBR" -- but you *do* need to do something that's logically equivalent; namely, to repair the boot loader. Chances are you just need to set the Windows boot loader to be the default, which can be done with [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html); however, it's possible that more extensive repairs are necessary.

Comment: Thanks, i solved the problem anyways, actually i wasn't even able to see the bios where it shows 'toshiba leading innovation' thing, but i connected my laptop to another display and tried to get into the boot mode and it worked, i could see it on that display but not on mine and i used my keyboard to toggle the settings and changed it to uefi again, and now everything works just fine. Although i don't know if i can install ubuntu because it'll again show that grub error like before :/ .